# Pandas: lining up tables extracted from html

Tags: html, pandas, datatables

I have many of these tables where the `read_html` doesn't exactly read tables correctly. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

l = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581018000047/nvda2018proxystatementsecf.htm'
df_list = pd.read_html(l)

df = df_list[85].dropna(how='all')
df = df.fillna('')

print df
```

How do I get further process it to get it to line up correctly? or is there another way to read it in correctly to start with.

Answer (score 3):

Your challenge is that you are facing a limitation of pandas read_html.

The table you try to parse has a "rowspan=2" defined which throws read_html as described in this [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17054)

one work around might be to code your own parser as described [here](https://johnricco.github.io/2017/04/04/python-html/)

Which in the own words of the writer are:

> The gist what’s going on here:
>
> First we parse the HTML using BeautifulSoup, finding all tables, then all rows within each table, then each cell within each row.
> Then when we’re looping over each of these cells, we check to see if there are any colspan and rowspan attributes associated with the cell – this tells us the dimensions of the cell. In spreadsheet terms, you might think of a rowspan value of 2 corresponding to a cell being merged with the cell below it.
> The colspan information is easy to use. If we register a colspan value greater than 1, we skip that number of columns before we start filling in the next cell.
> The rowspan information is a bit trickier. If we register a rowspan value greater than 1, we store it in a list (“skip_index”) where each element corresponds to a column in our table. When the loop is filling in data for each cell, it first checks to see if there’s a nonzero value in this column’s skip_index; if that’s true, it skips this column. With every row iteration, we increment each nonzero skip_index element by -1 until it’s back to zero.